# simple rendering logic for selected fields

Tags: python, django

I am rendering to this page by setting window.location.href to: `/edit_page/?id=user_id` in one of my page and in my views.py I have this:

```
id = request.GET.get('id') 
users = User.objects.all()
return render_to_response("index.html",{'id':id,'users':users},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and in my index.html, I have a select field with options which are users being rendered from server as you see in my dict, the select field is per default not selected.

the `ID` I have in my hand is the ID of a user who is selected to be edited in another page, but now how can I set the option to selected with the user whose ID is equal to `ID` which is "in my left hand".

hope, I explained well what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select>
{% for user in users %}
{% if id == user.id %}<option selected>{% else %}<option>{% endif %}{{ user.first_name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```